# OpenACC-OpenMP support Arm Mali GPU

Tags: arm, gpu, openmp, openacc, mali

I would like to ask if OpenACC or OpenMP support ARM Mali GPUs. I use OpenMP 4.0 which supports GPU parallelisation but I am not sure if it runs on the GPU. Do you have any idea how can I test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither are supported on Mali. Compute acceleration support is via OpenCL, or compute shaders in OpenGL ES / Vulkan.

Answer (score 1):

Either/both specifications would work fine on Mali GPUs, but I'm not aware of any compilers that support offloading to Mali. GCC or CLANG would be your best bet, but I don't think either has a Mali target compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The newly updated Arm C/C++ Compiler 21.1 with OpenMP 5.0 for Linux may support offloading to ARM MALI GPU targets.
[OpenMP 5.0 features are supported by Arm C/C++ Compiler](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101458/2110/Standards-support/OpenMP-5-0?lang=en)